# `as.matrix` and `as.data.frame` S3 methods vs. S4 methods

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

I noticed that defining `as.matrix` or `as.data.frame` as S3 methods for an S4 class
makes e.g. `lm (formula, objS4)` and `prcomp (object)` work out of the box. This doesn't work if they are defined as S4 methods.

Why does it matter whether the methods are defined as S3 or S4 method?

Example for `as.data.frame`:

```
setClass ("exampleclass", representation (x = "data.frame"))
object <- new ("exampleclass", x = iris)

setMethod ("as.data.frame", signature="exampleclass", definition= function (x, ...) x@x )
## [1] "as.data.frame"

as.data.frame (object)
## Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
## 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
## 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
## 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
## ...snip...

lm (Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, object)
## error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
##   cannot coerce class 'structure("exampleclass", package = ".GlobalEnv")' into a data.frame

as.data.frame.exampleclass <- function (x, ...) x@x

lm (Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, object)
## Call:
##   lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = object)
## 
## Coefficients:
##   (Intercept)  Petal.Width  
## 1.084        2.230
```

As the situation may be a bit complicated with `lm` where the coercion will only occur when the formula is evaluated in an environment constructed from the data, here is a more simple case whith the same behaviour:

```
setMethod ("as.matrix", signature="exampleclass", definition= function (x, ...) as.matrix (x@x[, 1:4]) )
prcomp (object)
## error in as.vector(data) : 
##   No method to coerce this S4 class into a vector
as.matrix.exampleclass <- function (x, ...) as.matrix (x@x [, 1:4])
prcomp (object)
##   Standard deviations:
##     [1] 2.0562689 0.4926162 0.2796596 0.1543862
##   
## Rotation:
##   PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
## Sepal.Length  0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
## Sepal.Width  -0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
## Petal.Length  0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
## Petal.Width   0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574
```

Here, `stats:::prcomp.default` is called, which starts with a plain `x <- as.matrix (x)`. This fails with the above S4 definition, but works with the S3 definition.

Comment: This is mentioned in the description of the `data` argument in `?lm` .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I'm aware that "objects coercible to data.frame" can be used - but I was expecting that this coercion could be enabled by providing an S4 method for `as.data.frame`. I clarified the question.

Comment: Do you use `setAs` for S4?

Comment: @hadley: `setAs` enables `as (object, "data.frame")`, but neither `lm` nor `prcomp` work that way.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if `as.data.frame` would try the S4 `as` method if needed.  It's confusing how many object coercion mechanisms there are.  You might want to try this question on R-devel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it from the comments that `lm` simply calls `as.data.frame` explicitly.  If you look at `as.data.frame`:

```
> as.data.frame
function (x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...) 
{
    if (is.null(x)) 
        return(as.data.frame(list()))
    UseMethod("as.data.frame")
}
<bytecode: 0x29140b8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

You'll see that it calls the S3 generic, and from the [methods documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/Methods.html)

> An S4 method alone will not be seen if the S3 generic function is called directly. However, >primitive functions and operators are exceptions: The internal C code will look for S4 >methods if and only if the object is an S4 object. In the examples, the method for `[` for >class "myFrame" will always be called for objects of this class.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I may add from that man page: **the recommended approach is to define the S3 method and also supply the identical function as the definition of the S4 method.** I hope that if I also provide `setAs`, the coercion compatibility complete. I'll carefully read the methods description again - maybe I'll come to an understanding why the direct call to `as.data.frame (object)` or `as.matrix (object)` works (I wouldn't expect that from the `? methods` documentation), but not from inside e.g. `prcomp`...