# R - Can't convert fPORTFOLIO object to matrix or data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, r-s4

My code is the following :

```
require("fPortfolio")
lppData <- 100 * LPP2005.RET[, 1:6]
ewSpec <- portfolioSpec()
nAssets <- ncol(lppData)
setWeights(ewSpec) <- rep(1/nAssets, times = nAssets)
ewPortfolio <- feasiblePortfolio(lppData,ewSpec)
```

I want to be able to convert ewPortfolio to a matrix or a data frame.

I have tried using the solution described here [`as.matrix` and `as.data.frame` S3 methods vs. S4 methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593021/as-matrix-and-as-data-frame-s3-methods-vs-s4-methods)

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I want to print ewPortfolio in Excel using Rexcel and it seems to only deal with data frame or matrix objects.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Which information do you want to keep? What in rows? What in columns?

Comment: I want to keep everything. Ideally it would keep the same display.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to write portfolio information created with fPortfolio in excel. I've found this code somewhere and it allows me to write the portfolio information to excel (you need to install xlsx package and java):

```
## Write output to excel

dir.create("AllPortfolios", showWarnings = FALSE)               
mywb <- createWorkbook()
mysheet <- createSheet(mywb, sheetName="Portfolio")
strcol <- 1
mytitle <- data.frame(efficient_Portfolio@title)
addDataFrame(mytitle , mysheet, startRow=1, startColumn=strcol)
myweights <- data.frame(efficient_Portfolio@portfolio@portfolio$weights)
addDataFrame(myweights , mysheet, startRow=3, startColumn=strcol)
strcol <- strcol + 2
mytgret <-  data.frame(efficient_Portfolio@portfolio@portfolio$targetReturn)
addDataFrame(mytargetreturn , mysheet, startRow=3, startColumn=strcol)
strcol <- strcol + 2
mytgrisk <- data.frame(efficient_Portfolio@portfolio@portfolio$targetRisk)
addDataFrame(mytargetrisk , mysheet, startRow=3, startColumn=strcol)
strcol <- strcol + 2
saveWorkbook(mywb, "./AllPortfolios/AllPortfolios.xlsx")
```